# Notify user of rejected edit

Tags: discussion, feature-request, proposed-edits

Can we have something in place to notify users (less than 2k) who propose an edit if their edit is declined?

More specifically (as it is easy enough to return to the question/answer to see if the edit has been approved), can something be included to give a reason for the rejection? Perhaps some things along the lines of

```
*Doesn't add anything/meaningless change (ie AmE spelling to BE)
*Adds incorrect information
*Changes the meaning of the original post
```

I think this would be useful to help guide users to better editing, as they know what type of edit suggestions to avoid in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is going to be implemented; see [What are the rejection reasons for suggested edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106867/what-are-the-rejection-reasons-for-suggested-edits) for more information.

At the moment, the list of reasons for rejecting an edit is being defined; after that, the new code will be deployed, first on Meta Stack Overflow, then on Stack Overflow, and the other SE sites.